# No CNAME records were found. Please add a CNAME record pointing to xxxx.azurewebsites.net

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, cname, custom-domain

I have been trying to add a custom domain name to an application I hosted on azure and am trying to link it to a domain i bought in https://www.whogohost.com. I have tried everything as specified in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain but to no avail, i keep getting the error (No CNAME records were found. Please add a CNAME record pointing to xxxx.azurewebsites.net).

Note: xxxx is just an alias for my App Name hosted in azure.

Please, is there anyone with relevant answers?

Comment: Do you check this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/857731/domain-ownership-error-no-cname-records-were-found-please-add-a-cname-record-p)?

Comment: @Shengbao Shui, the answers in the question you specified are contained in the link which was part of my question. I have tried those options. That's why I had to post the question here for expert opinions.

Answer (score 1):

The error itself will be with the domain name provider you bought the domain through. You will need to make sure that you have properly setup the CNAME and A name records in your DNS settings on that website. Such as my domain I have through GoDaddy:
[image]

Comment: I did properly set up those parameters. I went ahead to add TXT and A property in the domain's DNS when the CNAME was not working.

Comment: That is the correct action and is one of the options clearly documented in the Azure portal